# Locked Question for Done contest

Tags: discussion

I don't get why my question here: [Summation identity involving the floor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083170/summaton-of-factors)

is locked even though the due date for the contest was done last 10th December, 2014?

Answer (score 9):

After clearing the rest of the flag queue I had the time to take another look. Your claim was easy to verify (thanks to Brian M. Scott for giving the link). Unlocking. Sorry about this.

My first response below. Leaving it there in case somebody wants to criticize me further and is running out of ammo.

---

I was the moderator who locked the question in response to it being flagged.

I have been personally involved with math contests for a long time. In my youth as a competitor, and later as a referee and an organizer. Therefore I will enforce our policy on contest questions with possibly too much zeal. Anyway, my approach here is to lock first and investigate later.

The previous question you had posted was from an ongoing contest, well publicized in Meta.

Comment: I think this response is fine, given the potential for abuse from people cheating on contests. It should be the question-asker's responsibility to make it 100% clear that a question is from a contest, and that the contest has expired, when posting a question.